# Build the centos 7 and higher base Docker imagesvia Dockefile , /etc/init.d/functions not available

Tags: linux, centos, dockerfile

As part of  Building  Docker image with  centos7 or higher,  we're not able to find

> /etc/init.d/functions

Normally this is required as part of starting linux initscript. 
How to resolve this issues.As of now I downgraded the centos 6.6 version, Its is working and

> /etc/init.d/functions is avaiable

But time being we need to work withhigher version of centos.

Anybody can  help me  in that

Comment: You will have to convert to systemd for most modern Linux distros. Consider Slackware or Gentoo if you don't want to do that.

Comment: Can you share , how to convert to systemd  distro